# How to get detailed information about multiple tasks

Tags: gradle

In the documentation ([4.7.3 Show task usage details](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:show_task_details)), the text says that it is possible to have detailed information about one or **multiple** tasks using something like:

```
gradle -q help --task libs
```

This is working with one task (`libs`) in this case.

How can I print detailed info for **multiple** tasks? What is the format of the argument for `--task` for multiple tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the docs are unclear unfortunately: it's impossible to pass multiple task names to this command. If you have the following `build.gradle`:

```
task lib1

task lib2 {
    doLast {
        println "In lib2"
    }
}
```

And run:

```
gradle -q help --task lib1 lib2
```

it will just print the details about `lib1` and *execute* `lib2`.

*Multiple* in the docs means the situation when you have a multi-module project and named e.g. `whatever` is redefined in multiple modules. Then running:

```
gradle -q help --task whatever
```

from the root will print details about all `whatever` tasks.